# How do you survive the Defending the Keep mission?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I am level 33 at the moment, and the mission [Defending the Keep](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Defending_the_Keep) is intended to be completed at level 26. When the undead start arriving en masse, however, there is little I can do but die.

Playing as a Guardian, what is the best strategy to complete this mission? Which weapons, skills, and strategies should I focus on?

Comment: Is this the one on the island? With the trebuchets and the boats and stuff?

Comment: According to the link, it isn't -- it's way earlier in the storyline.

Comment: No clue then, it was a while ago i did that, but i could suggest using 2h sword or 2h hammer for some nice AOE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the strategy listed in the linked wiki page?

1. Pre-battle, load up on as much AOE as your profession can get.
2. Man the cannon at the top of the walkway
3. When you see a giant horde of undead coming, fire one last
   cannonball or grapeshot into them and then fall back. Don't wait for
   the NPCs to tell you to run away.
4. Do not attempt to fall back to the next canon. Move instead to the
   arrow launcher in the back and keep firing at the group near the
   NPCs.
5. When you die, don't keep rezzing repeatedly. Take one rez and AOE
   the biggest cluster you can find then take a break while the NPCs
   clear out some of the remaining undead.
6. Start rezzing and fighting again when the last NPC reaches about
   10-15% health. Don't worry too much about him. He has a lot of
   health.
7. Once the horde has been cleared out, don't go fighting the
   abominations but instead start rezzing the NPCs to do that for you

http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Defending_the_Keep

Comment: reason for downvote?

Comment: No clue, but my guess is that the asker already saw that and decided it doesn't work?

Comment: maybe. but the link was editted into the question by DavidYell.

Comment: Then I don't know... here have an upvote anyway :p